# Как рандомно заполнить таблицу?

Tags: mysql

Как рандомно заполнить таблицу, состоящую из 3 колонок, колонки имеют такие типы:

```
int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT - его заполнять не надо
varchar(150)
date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$b = rand(1111, 9999);
$c = date("d.m.Y");
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES ($a,$b,$c)");
```

В переменную $b пишем случайное число из диапазона, в $c текущую дату. После этого подаем запрос в базу, $a получает инремент, остальные поля согласно содержанию переменных. Это можно в цикле повторить, чтобы вставить более одной записи, или из массива с алфавитом выбрать случайные буквы для формирования случайной буквенной последовательности.

Comment: Т.к. **а** с **AI**, то в запросе он не нужен. Инкремент же идет в базе, а не в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный вариант на mysql:

```
INSERT INTO some_table SET row1 = FLOOR(1000*RAND()), row2 = FLOOR(9999*RAND());
```

Соотв. в row1 будет записываться число от 0 до 1000, в row2 от 0 до 9999. Можно смещать прибавляя или вычитая какое-нибудь значение при установки столбца.

Comment: Во второе поле надо рандомную дату писать, а не число.

Comment: Прошу прощения за невнимательность, но, вообщем-то, сгененировать дату, если она нужна рандомная, не самая большая проблема. Но, кстати, действительно проще это сделать на php ввиду того, что можно это дело забабахать в цикл.